# try - catch без метода

Tags: java, android

подскажите пожалуйста

есть try которая принимает значения из Edit и если значения есть, catch не должен выполняться. То есть берутся значения из полей потом идет перемножение, потом преобразование дробного с текст и вывести в Edit другой.  Но что то мне кажется что я неправильно делаю ибо вроде бы нельзя преобразовать дробное число в текст, а может я ошибаюсь.

У меня есть 4 EditText d 3 из них записываются значения дробные, в а 4 должен выводиться результат умножения без применения кнопки. в итоге при запуске в 4 поле просто написано 0.0 а при попытке ввода значения в 3 других поля ничего не происходит просто вставляются числа и все, перемножения не происходит

Можно ли сделать так что бы при вводе в 3 Edit автоматически результат переносился в 4 Edit не используя кнопку, что бы не захламлять экран приложения еще кнопкой.

```
package com.example.magictrans;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class fullcalc extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText doppoint1, doppoint3, doppoint2, point4;
        double a, b, c, d;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fullcalc);
            doppoint1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doppoint1);
            doppoint2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doppoint2);
            doppoint3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doppoint3);
            point4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.point4);
            
            try {
                a = Double.parseDouble(doppoint1.getText().toString());
                b = Double.parseDouble(doppoint2.getText().toString());
                c = Double.parseDouble(doppoint3.getText().toString());

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                a = 0;
                b = 0;
                c = 0;
            }
            d=a*b*c;
            String result = Double.toString(d);
            point4.setText(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: не закидывайте камнями только, много вопросов задаю, но это перемножение в голове уже не укладывается как реализовать))))вjavarush прохожу курсы но пока там сложно че то понять ибо базовая теория только

Comment: я мало что понял. А в чем проблема с этим кодом?

Comment: проблема в том что пытаюсь что бы перемножил через этот код. То есть в 3 Edit а дробные числа вводятся а в 4 Edit значение автоматом должно переводить без кнопки. В итоге уже неделю не могу понять как сделать код проклятый((((

Comment: так в чем проблема-то? нормально и понятно можешь описать? Ты запускаешь этот код и ... что происходит? Что такое 3 Edit, 4 Edit, где оно в коде?

Comment: У меня есть 4 EditText d 3 из них записываются значения дробные, в а 4 должен выводиться результат умножения без применения кнопки.
в итоге при запуске в 4 поле просто написано 0.0 а при попытке ввода значения в 3 других поля ничего не происходит просто вставляются числа и все, перемножения не происходит

Comment: и как к этому относится "try - catch без метода"?

Comment: onCreate выполняется один-единственный раз при запуске активити. Все ваши действия в этой активити методом onCreate никак не обрабатываются. И если вы не успеваете ввести свои числа в течение тех наносекунд, которые проходят от старта onCreate до обработки содержимого полей ввода, то a, b и c приравниваются к 0, все так, как и записано в коде.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что нужно создать отдельный цикл для данного действия?  например while для проверки истинности?

Comment: Нет, вам нужны обработчики событий. Самое простое: добавить кнопку и к ней слушатель, по нажатию кнопки делать расчёт. Другой вариант: на каждый `EditText` повесить `TextWatcher` (слушатель ввода) и делать расчёт в нём - результат будет меняться по мере ввода, но это сложнее реализовать.

Comment: жалко конечно, не хотелось добавлять кнопку) просто на сайте джаваскрипт такое может, думал в приложении тоже возможно будет.
Спасибо за помощь будем пытаться реализовать кнопку

Comment: Ну не хотите - пробуйте сразу `TextWatcher`, по сути принцип тот же, только запутаться проще.

Comment: я понял что второй способ еще сложнее, его пока нет смысла использовать. так ка с кнопкой я хотя бы знаком как ее делать))) просто думал тут как на джаваскрипте, сайт вроде такое умеет и думал приложение тоже сможет без сложностей)

Comment: см. ответ - это не сложно именно для этой задачи, но проблем не оберёшься если менять текст из самого слушателя в тех полях, к которым он прикреплён.

Comment: можете перед try заполнить свои поля числами (типа ``doppoint1.setText("2.3")``) и посмотреть, что получится.

Comment: я тоже так планировал сперва, но тогда пользователь не будет видеть что и куда вводить. Там просто в ячейках Hint элементы для обозначения что за ячейки, которые пропадают после активации ячейки. Вроде бы правильно написал)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Без метода никак: метод `onCreate` выполняется один раз при запуске активности, а поля заполняются когда-нибудь потом и не в один момент, поэтому здесь нужен слушатель для полей ввода - он реагирует на любое изменение в `EditText` и выполняет наш код.

```java
public class fullcalc extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                try {
                    a = Double.parseDouble(doppoint1.getText().toString());
                    b = Double.parseDouble(doppoint2.getText().toString());
                    c = Double.parseDouble(doppoint3.getText().toString());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    a = 0;
                    b = 0;
                    c = 0;
                }
                d=a*b*c;
                String result = Double.toString(d);
                point4.setText(result);
            }

        }

        EditText doppoint1, doppoint3, doppoint2, point4;
        double a, b, c, d;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.fullcalc);
            doppoint1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doppoint1);
            doppoint2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doppoint2);
            doppoint3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.doppoint3);
            point4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.point4);
            doppoint1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            doppoint2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
            doppoint3.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
        }
}
```

Comment: Я хотел бы сказать огромное спасибо за предоставленный код и знания, делает то что нужно. Теперь буду изучать этот метод что бы понимать что он делает и на что способен.
Еще раз огромное спасибо.